# Created Files are saved in another folder

Tags: texmaker

The file I run is in a folder, and runs without issues. However, the created files (.pdf, .aux, .dvi..) are saved in an automatically created subfolder, `build`. It did not use to happen in the past, and now I don't know what I have changed.

This makes it a bit annoying when I go and look for the pdf files, and at first it was even confusing. It happens with all files, so I guess it's a `texmaker` setting but I can't find it.

Where can I change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TeXMaker, go to Options -> Configure TeXmaker

[image]

Uncheck 'Use a "Build" subdirectory for output files' and you're done.